# Transferring data between two components which have no any relations with each other using VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a component which is receiving data from it's Parent as a prop to list that data, now I'm fetching the data from an API and send it to the child component, now I want to fetch data once then send it to all my child component' Parents to list the same data in different views

Answer (score 2):

You can to try  [Vuex](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/when-and-how-to-use-vuex-270f83c8d12a)

I suggestion for you to watch documentation intro for understanding this https://vuex.vuejs.org/

And if you dont want to use outside dependency you can look : [event bus pattern](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2020/01/06/handling-events-vue-js/) (but it not best solution for your case)